# How do I create a custom Reactive Form Element?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I'm working with Reactive Forms in Angular and I'm trying to create a custom form element so I can use buttons with my form. I'm trying to follow a tutorial from [Alligator.io](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/), but it isn't clear how to integrate this into my component. Currently I'm getting the following error.

```
ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'coverage_for_domestic_partners'
```

Below is my code any help would be appreciated.

// HTML

```
<div class="button-group" [formGroup]="group">
    <button
        *ngFor="let option of config.options"
        class="button button--toggle"
        [ngClass]='{"is-active": option.selected}'
        (click)="select($event, option)"
        [formControlName]="config.key">
        <div class="button-content">{{option.key}}</div>
    </button>
</div>
```

// Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, forwardRef, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'z-toggle-group',
 templateUrl: './z-toggle-group.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./z-toggle-group.component.scss'],
 providers: [
{
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => ZToggleGroupComponent),
  multi: true
}
  ]


 })
export class ZToggleGroupComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

@Input() config;
@Input() group: FormGroup;

@Input() disabled = false;
  @HostBinding('style.opacity')
  get opacity() {
    return this.disabled ? 0.25 : 1;
  }

clicked;

onChange = (rating: number) => {};
onTouched = () => {};

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
    // console.log('form', this.group)
      this.group.get(this.config.key).valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        console.log('formValue', value);
    })
}

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }

select($event, option) {
    this.clicked = $event;
    this.group.get(this.config.key).patchValue(option.value, {onlySelf: true});

    this.config.options.forEach(option => {
        option.selected = false;
    })

    option.selected = true;
}

}
```

Comment: Where is
  `writeValue(obj: any): void`
  `registerOnChange(fn: any): void`
  `registerOnTouched(fn: any): void` implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy and paste that initially. I'm not sure how to integrate those into my function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface, to do this, you will need to implement this methods:

```
interface ControlValueAccessor {
  writeValue(obj: any): void
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean)?: void
}
```

You can see my example implementation right [here](https://github.com/thomazcapra/manage-portal/blob/master/src/app/core/components/input/input.component.ts).

When your component's value changes, you have to call `OnChange` method, that you registered in your ts file.

You can see my call example [here](https://github.com/thomazcapra/manage-portal/blob/master/src/app/core/components/input/input.component.html).

After that, you can use your component by its tag selector (in your case `z-toggle-group`) inside a form, and you will be able to use `formControlName`.

```
<div class="button-group" [formGroup]="group">
    <button
        *ngFor="let option of config.options"
        class="button button--toggle"
        [ngClass]='{"is-active": option.selected}'
        (click)="select($event, option)">

        <z-toggle-group [formControlName]="config.key"></z-toggle-group>

        <div class="button-content">{{option.key}}</div>
    </button>
</div>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zowbqn) is your code working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is a little confusing. I'm suppose to add <z-toggle-group> to itself?

Comment: Thank you Thomaz! Your answer was very thorough.

Comment: This is a buried gem. Thanks a lot @ThomazCapra